# What is the equivalent of ItemAddResult in @pnp/sp?

Tags: spfx

I'm getting `'node_modules/@pnp/sp has no exported member 'ItemAddResult''`
when I'm importing ItemAddResult at the top of a SharePoint Sfpx webpart:

`import { sp, ItemAddResult, AttachmentFileInfo } from "@pnp/sp";`

I'm also getting the same message for: AttachmentFileInfo.

In the docs it suggests to import ItemAddResult:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/items/#add-items

Now that the old sp-pnp-js library has been deprecated, I'm forced(?) to use this new library.

I've run npm install on the project dir.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2 use `import { IItemAddResult } from "@pnp/sp/items";`

Please have a look to the docs: [Add Items](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#add-items)

Comment: Sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

@pnp/sp version(2.11.0) works for me

Try to uninstall @pnp/sp

npm uninstall @pnp/sp
Then install this version

npm i @pnp/sp@2.11.0

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for non-code.